# PHP Add Interger with BindParam not Working

Tags: php, pdo

I built function that get query and params and execute it:

```
public static function doQuery($Query, $Params = array())
    {
        $psth = self::$dbh->prepare($Query);

        foreach ($Params as $param => $value)
        {
            if (!is_numeric($value)){
                echo "$value is not numeric \n";
                $psth->bindParam($param, $value, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
            else{
                echo "$value is numeric \n";
                $psth->bindParam($param, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
        }
        $psth->execute();
        return $psth;
     }
```

When I run this query: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category = :CatId LIMIT 4` without the limit param (The CatId param is good) Its working,
But when I am using my function like this:

```
$limit = 4;
$SParamsQuery = array(
       ":CatId" => $CatId,
       ":x" => 4
                     );           
$SQuery = self::doQuery('SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category = :CatId LIMIT :x',$SParamsQuery);
```

This is not working.

Any Ideas how to solve it?

Dump Params:

```
SQL: [58] SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `Category` = :CatId LIMIT 4
Params:  1
Key: Name: [6] :CatId
paramno=-1
name=[6] ":CatId"
is_param=1
param_type=1
```

Thanks
Haim.

Comment: What do you mean by, "this is not working"?

Comment: shouldn't be any reason why it's not working. Did you check for boolean false return values and/or a try/catch block if you enabled exceptions?

Comment: I mean that is return null, I will add the DumpParams

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it works if you replace

```
$psth->bindParam($param, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

with

```
$psth->bindParam($param, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT); //without backslash
```

Comment: I must do this, because I am using my custom namespace(This is not my problem) :(